# How to count records based on subset of data in googlesheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table of tickets assigned to users. The tickets are either in *Open*, *Closed* or *Resolved* state.

[image: owner]

I'm able to create the list of owners using the formula:

```
=UNIQUE(D9:D20)
```

I'm also able to generate the number of total issues against each user using the formula:

```
=COUNTIF(D9:D20, A2)
```

But now I need to calculate the number of *Open*, *Closed* or *Resolved* issues for each individual users.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1):

=QUERY(C8:D,"select D,COUNT(D) where D<>'' group by D pivot C order by COUNT(D) desc",1)

then just make a totals column to the right of the three statuses and do a SUM() of each row

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using this formula:

```
={{query({C1:D, C1:C},"Select Col2, count(Col1) 
  where Col2 is not null 
  group by Col2 
  pivot Col3 limit 0",1),"Total Issues"};
 query(query({C1:D, C1:C},"Select Col2, count(Col1) 
  where Col2 is not null 
  group by Col2 
  pivot Col3",1),"Select Col1 offset 1",0),
 ARRAYFORMULA(N(query(query({C1:D, C1:C},"Select Col2, count(Col1) 
  where Col2 is not null 
  group by Col2 
  pivot Col3",1),"Select Col2, Col3, Col4 offset 1",0))),
 query(query({C1:D, C1:C},"Select Col2, count(Col1) 
  where Col2 is not null 
  group by Col2",1),"Select Col2 offset 1",0)}
```

### Output:

[image]

[image]

### Additional Reference:

- [Replace Blank Cells with 0 in Query Pivot in Google Sheets](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/replace-blank-cells-with-0-in-query-pivot/)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to create [a pivot table](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1272900).

I've got my final version set up like this...

[image: Google Sheet with pivot table]

Steps:

1. Delete the current summary table you have above your data table. Columns A:D can only contain data and the column headers.
2. Select columns A:D
3. Data > Pivot table - Existing sheet - Sheet1!F1
4. In the Pivot table editor panel on the right...

   1. Rows - Add - Owner
   2. Columns - Add - Status
   3. Values - Add - Ticket # - Summarize by - COUNT
   4. Filters - Add - Owner - Status - Uncheck (Blanks)

You can tweak it from there. As you add data to the bottom of the table, it will automatically update the pivot table. NOTE: If you add a new owner, you will need to update the Filter and place a check beside their name.